# How to handle Junk characters in Sqoop

Tags: sqoop

When importing data from RDMS to Hadoop using sqoop. If my source system contains junk charactesrs how can we replace them

Eg: 1,punâ€,travel,

Comment: Can you please post your Sqoop command as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *junk* characters can vary based on data being stored and usage of the data. `Sqoop` import allows dropping `Hive` delimiters (via `--hive-drop-import-delims` option) or replacing `Hive` delimiters (via `--hive-delims-replacement` option). Other forms of data processing would need to be done after import job has landed data on Hadoop.

Per the Sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html):

```
--hive-drop-import-delims: Drops \n, \r, and \01 from string fields when importing to Hive.
--hive-delims-replacement: Replace \n, \r, and \01 from string fields with user defined string when importing to Hive.
```

Comment: Need to import data into hdfs directory not using hive

Comment: Even though both options have `hive-` as part of their name, they will also work when importing data to `HDFS`.

Comment: Thanks for the info